# Solving ODE using power series method but get the general solution $y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Given ODE
$$x^2y'-y=0,\qquad x\neq 0.$$
Solve given ODE using power series method.

Let $$y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots.$$
Then,
$$y'=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^4+\ldots.$$
Now, we substitute to ODE then we have

\begin{align}
&x^2\left( a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^4+\ldots\right)-\left( a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots \right)=0\\
\iff& -a_0-a_1x+(a_1-a_2)x^2+(2a_2-a_3)x^3+(3a_3-a_4)x^4+\ldots=0
\end{align}

Comparing LHS and RHS we have
\begin{align}
a_0=0\\
a_1=0\\
a_2=a_1=0\\
a_3=2a_2=0\\
a_4=3a_3=0\\
\vdots
\end{align}

So, we have general solution of ODE
$y=0+0x+0x^2+0x^3+\ldots=0$.

Why if use power series method for this problem we have the general solution $y=0$?

But, the correct general solution is $y=Ce^{-\frac{1}{x}}$.

How to get solution for this problem using power series method?

Comment: you can't use power series nor frobenius series on this. zero is not a regular singular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-1/x}$ has no power series representation centered at $x_0=0$, since $0$ is a singularity of the function. You could, however, try to find a Laurent series instead. That is, a series of the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_kx^k$.

You will obtain $a_{k}=\frac{(-1)^k a_0}{(-k)!}$ for $k\leq0$, and thus $y(x)=a_0\exp(-1/x)$.